# Networkx Multigraph from_pandas_dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

**Update:**
**The question, as written, is relevant to Networkx version < 2.0. The `from_pandas_dataframe` method [has been dropped](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/release/release_2.0.html).**
**To accomplish the same task in Networkx >= 2.0, see the update to the accepted answer.**

Trying to create a [`MultiGraph()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/classes.multigraph.html#networkx.MultiGraph) instance from a pandas DataFrame using networkx's [`from_pandas_dataframe`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.11/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_dataframe.html).  What am I doing wrong in the example below?

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
        import networkx as nx

        df = pd.DataFrame([['geneA', 'geneB', 0.05, 'method1'],
                           ['geneA', 'geneC', 0.45, 'method1'],
                           ['geneA', 'geneD', 0.35, 'method1'],
                           ['geneA', 'geneB', 0.45, 'method2']], 
                           columns = ['gene1','gene2','conf','type'])
```

First try with the default nx.Graph():

```
In [2]: G= nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'gene1', 'gene2', edge_attr=['conf','type'], 
                                    create_using=nx.Graph())
```

As a non-MultiGraph(), I'm missing one of the duplicate edges:

```
In [3]: G.edges(data=True)
Out[3]: [('geneA', 'geneB', {'conf': 0.45, 'type': 'method2'}),
         ('geneA', 'geneC', {'conf': 0.45, 'type': 'method1'}),
         ('geneA', 'geneD', {'conf': 0.35, 'type': 'method1'})]
```

With `MultiGraph()`:

```
In [4]: MG= nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'gene1', 'gene2', edge_attr=['conf','type'], 
                             create_using=nx.MultiGraph())
```

This:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-d2c7b8312ea7> in <module>()
----> 1 MG= nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'gene1', 'gene2', ['conf','type'], create_using=nx.MultiGraph())

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx-1.10-py2.7.egg/networkx/convert_matrix.pyc in from_pandas_dataframe(df, source, target, edge_attr, create_using)
    209         # Iteration on values returns the rows as Numpy arrays
    210         for row in df.values:
--> 211             g.add_edge(row[src_i], row[tar_i], {i:row[j] for i, j in edge_i})
    212 
    213     # If no column names are given, then just return the edges.

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/networkx-1.10-py2.7.egg/networkx/classes/multigraph.pyc in add_edge(self, u, v, key, attr_dict, **attr)
    340             datadict.update(attr_dict)
    341             keydict = self.edge_key_dict_factory()
--> 342             keydict[key] = datadict
    343             self.adj[u][v] = keydict
    344             self.adj[v][u] = keydict

TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

***Question***
How do I instantiate a `MultiGraph()` from a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Networkx < 2.0:**
It's was a bug, I opened an issue on GitHub, once I made the suggested [edit](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/1982):

It changed line 211 of `convert_matrix.py` to to read:

```
g.add_edge(row[src_i], row[tar_i], attr_dict={i:row[j] for i, j in edge_i})
```

Results from that change: *(which have since been incorporated)*

```
MG= nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'gene1', 'gene2', edge_attr=['conf','type'], 
                                 create_using=nx.MultiGraph())

MG.edges(data=True)
[('geneA', 'geneB', {'conf': 0.05, 'type': 'method1'}),
         ('geneA', 'geneB', {'conf': 0.45, 'type': 'method2'}),
         ('geneA', 'geneC', {'conf': 0.45, 'type': 'method1'}),
         ('geneA', 'geneD', {'conf': 0.35, 'type': 'method1'})]
```

**Networkx >= 2.0:**
In DataFrames with this format (edge list), use [`from_pandas_edgelist`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html#networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist)

```
MG= nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'gene1', 'gene2', edge_attr=['conf','type'], 
                             create_using=nx.MultiGraph())

MG.edges(data=True)
MultiEdgeDataView([('geneA', 'geneB', {'conf': 0.05, 'type': 'method1'}),
                   ('geneA', 'geneB', {'conf': 0.45, 'type': 'method2'}),
                   ('geneA', 'geneC', {'conf': 0.45, 'type': 'method1'}), 
                   ('geneA', 'geneD', {'conf': 0.35, 'type': 'method1'})])
```

Comment: This is accepted answer, but as per documentation:  https://pelegm-networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.MultiDiGraph.add_edge.html when I create edges I can specify the key for parallel edges, and then also the attributes. With this answer, I see I can set the attributes. How can I specify the key?

Answer (score 4):

That's a nice question. I tried to reproduce your problem building your `MultiGraph()` in a different way, using only three/four columns with:

```
MG = nx.MultiGraph()

MG.add_weighted_edges_from([tuple(d) for d in df[['gene1','gene2','conf']].values])
```

this correctly returns as `MG.edges(data=True)`:

```
[('geneA', 'geneB', {'weight': 0.05}), ('geneA', 'geneB', {'weight': 0.45}), ('geneA', 'geneC', {'weight': 0.45}), ('geneA', 'geneD', {'weight': 0.35})]
```

I tried also with your `from_pandas_dataframe` method using only three columns but it doesn't work:

```
MG = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'gene1', 'gene2', edge_attr='conf', create_using=nx.MultiGraph())
```

this returns the same error you encountered. I don't know if it is a bug or that method doesn't support more than one weight type for `MultiGraph()`. In the meantime you can use the above workaround to build your MultiGraph, at least with only one weight type. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'll use the workaround for now, thanks, interested to see if anyone has seen similar error.

Comment: @Kevin ...2 years after, I got the same error. In my case, I am trying to create a `MultiDiGraph()`, but got the same error as you. This answer solved my problem too