# Creating Network Graphs

Tags: graph, social-networking

My sample data set in CSV format looks as follows.

The undirected graph has 90 nodes represented with numbers {10,11,12....99}
whose edges with weights are defined as follows.

[sample data]

```
node1 node2 weight
23     89    34.9  (i.e. there is an edge between node 23 and 89 with weight 34.9)
75     14    28.5
so on....
```

I would like to represent this in network form. What is the effective way to represent it (for example Gephi, networkx, etc). Thickness of the edge should represent edge weight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are in Linux, and assuming your csv file looks like this (for example):

```
23;89;3.49
23;14;1.29
75;14;2.85
14;75;2.9
75;23;0.9
23;27;4.9
```

You may use this program:

```
import os

def build_G(csv_file):

    #init graph dict
    g={}

    #here we open csv file
    with open(csv_file,'r') as f:
        cont=f.read()

    #here we get field content
    for line in cont.split('\n'):
        if line != '':

            fields=line.split(';')

            #build origin node
            if g.has_key(fields[0])==False:
                g[fields[0]]={}

            #build destination node         
            if g.has_key(fields[1])==False:
                g[fields[1]]={}

            #build edge origin>destination
            if g[fields[0]].has_key(fields[1])==False:
                g[fields[0]][fields[1]]=float(fields[2])

    return g

def main():

    #filename
    csv_file="mynode.csv"

    #build graph
    G=build_G(csv_file)

    #G is now a python dict
    #G={'27': {}, '75': {'14': 2.85, '23': 0.9}, '89': {}, '14': {'75': 2.9}, '23': {'27': 4.9, '89': 3.49, '14': 1.29}}


    #write to file
    f = open('dotgraph.txt','w')
    f.writelines('digraph G {\nnode [width=.3,height=.3,shape=octagon,style=filled,color=skyblue];\noverlap="false";\nrankdir="LR";\n')
    f.writelines

    for i in G:
        for j in G[i]:
            #get weight
            weight = G[i][j]
            s= '      '+ i
            s +=  ' -> ' +  j + ' [dir=none,label="' + str(G[i][j]) + '",penwidth='+str(weight)+',color=black]'
            if s!='      '+ i:
                s+=';\n'
                f.writelines(s)

    f.writelines('}')
    f.close()

    #generate graph image from graph text file
    os.system("dot -Tjpg -omyImage.jpg dotgraph.txt")

main()
```

I was previously looking for an effective solution to built complex graph and this is the most simple (without any python module dependency) method I found.

Here is the image result for an undirected graph (using **dir=none**):

[image]

Comment: You may use `sudo apt-get install graphviz` from your terminal if **dot** binary is not existing on your system

Comment: @ Stefani Thanks..!! 
My graph is undirected, How can I remove the directions.

Comment: @user1659936 You are welcome, you need to add **dir=none** during construction,  so  please replace the line : `s +=  ' -> ' +  j + ' [label="' + str(G[i][j]) + '",penwidth='+str(weight)+',color=black]'`  by  `s +=  ' -> ' +  j + ' [dir=none,label="' + str(G[i][j]) + '",penwidth='+str(weight)+',color=black]'` to remove direction

Comment: @user1659936: I change the code according to your need. Regards

Comment: Using the code above, my `dotgraph.txt` file was generated (seemingly) correctly on Windows, but I can't find the `.png` output. How can I get this to work on Windows and not just Linux?

Comment: Did you try JPEG or Gif extension ? (Microsoft is not friend with free file format...)

Answer (score 6):

Using [networkx](https://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/networkx-1.11/tutorial/tutorial.html), you can add edges with attributes

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(23, 89, weight=34.9)
G.add_edge(75, 14, weight=28.5)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have a large csv I'd recommend using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for the I/O portion of your task.  `networkx` has a useful method to interface with `pandas` called [`from_pandas_dataframe`](http://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_dataframe.html).  Assuming your data is in a csv in the format you stated above, this command should work for you:

```
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv', columns=['node1', 'node2', 'weight'])
```

But for demonstration I'll use 10 random edges within your requirements (you won't need to import `numpy`, I'm just using it for random number generation):

```
import matplotlib as plt
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

#Generate Random edges and weights
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0) # for reproducibility

w = np.random.rand(10) # weights 0-1
node1 = np.random.randint(10,19, (10))  # I used 10-19 for demo
node2 = np.random.randint(10,19, (10))
df = pd.DataFrame({'node1': node1, 'node2': node2, 'weight': w}, index=range(10))
```

Everything in the previous block should generate the same as your `pd.read_csv` command.  Resulting in this DataFrame, `df`:

```
    node1   node2   weight
0   16  13  0.548814
1   17  15  0.715189
2   17  10  0.602763
3   18  12  0.544883
4   11  13  0.423655
5   15  18  0.645894
6   18  11  0.437587
7   14  13  0.891773
8   13  13  0.963663
9   10  13  0.383442
```

Use `from_pandas_dataframe` to initialize [`MultiGraph`](http://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/networkx-1.11/tutorial/tutorial.html#multigraphs).  This assumes you will have multiple edges connecting to one node (not specified in OP).  To use this method, you will have to make an easy change in `networkx` source code in the `convert_matrix.py` file, implemented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210724/networkx-multigraph-from-pandas-dataframe) (it was a simple bug).

```
MG = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 
                              'node1', 
                              'node2', 
                               edge_attr='weight',
                               create_using=nx.MultiGraph()
                              )
```

This generates your MultiGraph, you can visualize it utilizing [`draw`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw):

```
positions = nx.spring_layout(MG) # saves the positions of the nodes on the visualization
# pass positions and set hold=True
nx.draw(MG, pos=positions, hold=True, with_labels=True, node_size=1000, font_size=16)
```

In detail:
`positions` is a dictionary where each node is a key and the value is a position on the graph.  I'll describe why we store `positions` below.  The generic `draw` will draw your MultiGraph instance `MG` with the nodes at the specified `positions`.  However, as you can see the edges are all the same width:
[image: Unweighted]

But you have everything you need to add the weights.  First get the weights into a list called `weights`.  Iterating (with list comprehension) through each edge with [`edges`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.edges.html), we can extract the weights.  I chose to multiply by `5` because it looked the cleanest:

```
weights = [w[2]['weight']*5 for w in  MG.edges(data=True)]
```

Finally we'll use [`draw_networkx_edges`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges), which only draws the edges of the graph (no nodes).  Since we have the `positions` of the nodes, and we set `hold=True`, we can draw weighted edges right on top of our previous visualization.

```
nx.draw_networkx_edges(MG, pos=positions, width=weights) #width can be array of floats
```

[image: Weighted]

You can see node `(14, 13)` has the heaviest line and the largest value from the DataFrame `df` (besides the `(13,13)`).

Comment: at nx.Multigraph() i am getting this error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Comment: It should work if you make the change noted in the paragraph right before that code block.  [Another link to the SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35210724/networkx-multigraph-from-pandas-dataframe) & the [GH Issue](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/1982).  Also, it will work if you remove the `create_using` argument altogether, only if you know that your graph is a `Graph` and not a `MultiGraph`.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the line at the beginning of the csv file as follows:

source target type weight
23     89    undirected  34.9  (i.e. there is an edge between node 23 and 89 with weight 34.9)
75     14    undirected  28.5
so on....

After that you can import the csv file into Gephi to represent the graph which the thickness of the edges stands for the weight, for example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTtme.png)